# SQLAlchemy JSON column contains specific key in nested json

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

is there any possibility to check if there is a specific key in list of dicts in JSON column?

SO far i have tried:

```
session.query(
    SomeClass
).filter(
    [r for r in SomeClass.some_json_column["key_that_contains_list_value"] 
    if r.get("inner_dict_key")]
)
```

This is the functionality I need, but it does not seem to work because I do get

```
AttributeError: Neither 'BinaryExpression' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'get'
```

Alternatively it would be sufficient just to find that key in anywhere in said JSON so I have tried also

```
.filter("inner_dict_key" in str(SomeClass.some_json_column))
```

but that does not work either.

Any idea how to implement this?

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Kinda made it work with `.filter(SomeClass.some_json_column["key_that_contains_list_value"][0].has_key('inner_dict_key'))`

because in my case list always contains at least one entry, but as you can imagine it does not give all the answers. It is quite ok for my testing purposes for now. Although I would really like to know if somebody got better answer.